# Does a python module somehow keep track of its global variables across multiple imports?

Tags: python, list, pointers, module, python-import

So I have a module for logging, into which I'm trying to implement the ability to subscribe to logs. On a very basic level it looks something like this.

```
subscribers = []

def subscribe(handler: Callable):
    subscribers.append(handler)

def log(msg: str):
    print(str)
    for sub in subscribers:
        sub(msg)
```

Now based on what I know about python, it should create a new *subscribers* list with every new import... But it doesn't. If I change the list in *a.py*, the changes occur in *b.py* etc. I don't mind this at all, it makes my job easier. But at the same time I'm not sure if I can rely on this working 100% of the time. So will it? Is my understanding of module imports wrong?

P.S. I know the best way to implement this feature would be to pass on an instance of a Logger class, but the thing I'm working on would probably need rebuilding from ground up.

Comment: Yes, Python keeps track of which modules have been imported. If you import it a second time, it doesn't re-execute the script, it just updates namespaces as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

it dose create a new subscribers list with every new run not every new import
it shares same list between all imports